# Using COUNTIF formula, but getting 0 in output

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

I am using =COUNTIF(A356:A396,140) formula, but I am getting 0 in the output. Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong

//Have attached an image of the excel [image]sheet

Comment: If your condition is 140 - you should look in column B for it, not column A

Comment: @Ike, thanks - didn’t realise!